# Can't create a react native empty project, app.json not found

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I am currently trying to get started with react native.

I set up the development environment referring to the documentation, but can't even pass the first step and create an empty project.

I am on Windows 11, Node 16.15.1, and NPM 8.12.2

I keep getting the following error when trying to init react-ative project with `expo init awesomeProject`

```
Error downloading and extracting template package: Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
× Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template.

Can't read JSON file: D:\crna\awesomeProject\app.json
└─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\crna\awesomeProject\app.json'
```

[image: screenshot of the error transcribed above]

Does anyone has a suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Clear your npm cache and try again.
You can use the command "npm cache clean --force" to clear your cache.
This may help if your cache is corrupted or contains invalid data.
I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Same error.

Probably there are something wrong with npx/npm, try `npx -v` or `npm -v` to check if npx/npm works properly.

I found my npm/npx system environment variable path is duplicated and after I deleted the wrong one and reboot my system, it works.

Then I tried `expo init` and everything goes perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Don't really know what is the problem but i found a soluion that might help other people in the same situation as me! like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61968287/7061272) just run in CMD instead of GitBash

Answer (score -1):

Use sudo if on linux. And maybe Admin on windows.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Take the [tour] and have a look at [answer], it should help explain that you'll need to back up your answer to explain why you think it's correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32708201)